# I am unable to extrude this plane along z-axis.Why?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, extrude

[image: screenshot]

I saw in youtube video a guy extruded a plane along the z-axis but I couldnt do it.

Comment: Extrude may work here. But maybe you don't see it if you are in top ortho view. Try again placing yourself in front view (numpad1). If this is still not working upload your file using this link : http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: I did but it just tranforms the plane in xy axis

Comment: do you hit any other key except E ?

Comment: I tried E > esc > G > Z > -4 this and it did not work but then I made a new file and it did

Comment: probably you have unfortunately changed some short cut in the previous file ? Is all ok now ?

Comment: yeah, have to do it all again now and thx

Answer (score 3):

Going from what you already have selected, all you have to do is press <kbd>E</kbd>. Blender will automatically start the transformation locked to the face normal, which in your case is along the global Z axis.

As lemon pointed out in the comments, from the view in your screen shot (orthographic view) you will not be able to perceive any change in height.